# Set up a highchart export server without Java

Tags: export, highcharts

I want to set up a server-sided chart rendering and saving as an image in order to create reports. I want to do this without Java. If I understood that right, it is possible only with PHP and JS and it runs properly, when there are less than 1500 datapoints. Is that right, or do I need Java despite?
Unfortunately I fail within the first steps.
Firstly I want to set up the job on a local test-environment.
My file system  is as follows:

D:/xampp/htdocs/chartExport

-- index.php

-- demo.html

---- /js

-------- highcharts-convert.js

-------- highcharts-more.js

-------- highcharts.js

-------- jquery-1.8.2.js

-------- /tmp

The problem is, that  the index.php stops on the point where the path to the phantom_js is proved.
I’m a little bit confused about the help remarks because in the example  sourcecode there are in the one hand defined the path and in the other hand the script with the folder where it is stored.
I have tried out lots of different combinations of absolute and relative paths with only the scriptname and things like js/highcharts-convert.js
What have I to define for the path and the script?
I think it should look like that:

```
define ('PHANTOMJS_PATH', 'js/');     
define ("PHANTOMJS_SCRIPT", 'highcharts-convert.js');     
define("TMP_DIR", "js/tmp");
```

But it doesn’t. Is it necessary to define absolute paths?

Comment: Ok, obviously it was a problem with file-rights. I've put the files on a non-local sever and gave the folder the necessary rights and this problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a fault in the readme file. This is how it should be;

```
// PATH TO PHANTOMJS EXECUTABLE
define ('PHANTOMJS_PATH', '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs');
// PATH TO HIGHCHARTS PHANTOM SCRIPT
define ("PHANTOMJS_SCRIPT", 'highcharts-convert.js');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Did I get that right, that there have to be stored an executable file on the server and that one must been compiled by myself?

Comment: Yes you have to upload the phantomjs executable to the server. From my own experience, you do not have to compile it perse on the server. If you could, it would be the best, I guess